# How to get multiple selected items from Form in Flask

Tags: python, flask

With the `<form>` having two list items selected "Category 01" and "Category 03":

```
<form> 
    <div class="form-group">
      <div>
        <select name='category' multiple class="form-control">
            <option> Category 01 </option>
            <option> Category 01 </option>
            <option> Category 01 </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image]

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    as_dict = request.form.to_dict()
    print request
```

Which prints this output showing it only gets a single "Category 03".

```
{'category': u'Category 01'}
```

How to make sure all the selected Categories are listed and not just one?

Comment: What if you just print `request.form`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will want to use the [`getlist()` function](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist) to get a list of values.

First, change your form as below:

```
<form> 
    <div class="form-group">
      <div>
        <select id="myform" name='category' multiple class="form-control"> // addition here
            <option> Category 01 </option>
            <option> Category 01 </option>
            <option> Category 01 </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And in your flask function:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    as_dict = request.form.getlist('myform')
    print request
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i have done this its working but in database `"custom_detail" : [
  "[object Object]",
  "[object Object]"
 ]
` it is saving like this im using pymongo as databse , how can i get actual data ??

Answer (score 2):

So problem is that the `to_dict()` by default flattens all inputs into a single layer dictionary.
Since the multiple selections are sent with the same key when they are added to the dictionary only the first one succeeds as a dict can not have multiple entries with the same key.

The resolution is to set `request.form.to_dict(flat=False)`. `flat=false` this means that all fields are returned as lists. So all the single fields will now be a single item in a list. But the multiple select will have all the selections in its list.