# Flask: Use multiple instances of one form

Tags: python, list, flask, wtforms

My website lets a teacher create multiple questions for an assignment. Once the assignment is created, a student can come and write an answer for each question.

My problem is that only one answer is saved for each entry. For example, there are two questions in an assignment. The answer for question 1 is "asdf", the answer for question 2 is "fdsa". The content for both answers will be saved as "asdf", when they should be unique.

I have tried printing `request.form` and it looks like this (excluding the csrf_tokens):
`('code_content', 'asdf'), ('code_content', 'fdsa'), ('submit', 'Submit Assignment')]`
So I know that fdsa is still in there somewhere, but I'm not able to access it. If this is important, there were two csrf_tokens that were the exact same when printing request.form.

To get that data, I created a 'GetQuestionContent()' form for as many questions in the assignment. Like this:

```
    questions = []
    question_content_forms = []
    for question in Question.query.all():
        if int(question.owner) == int(assignment_id):
            questions.append(question)

    question_content_forms = [GetQuestionContent() for item in range(0, len(questions))]
```

Then, in the HTML, I write the form like this:

```
<form method="POST">
{% for question in questions %}
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading{{ question.id }}">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" 
             type="button" 
             data-bs-toggle="collapse" 
             data-bs-target="#collapse{{ question.id }}" 
             aria-expanded="false" 
             aria-controls="collapse{{ question.id }}">
                 {{ question.title }}
             </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapse{{ question.id }}" 
        class="accordion-collapse collapse" 
        aria-labelledby="heading{{ question.id }}" 
        data-bs-parent="#questionsAccordion">
            <p>
                <small>
                    <strong>Question Description</strong>
                    <br>
                    {% if question.description != "" %}
                    {{ question.description|safe }}
                    {% else %}
                    <em>The assignment creator did not provide a description for this question.</em>
                    {% endif %}
                </small>
            </p>
            {{ question_content_forms[loop.index - 1].hidden_tag() }}
            {% if question.type == "code" %}
                <div class="code-box">
                    {{ question_content_forms[loop.index - 1].code_content(id = "editor") }}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            {% if question.type == "text" %}
                {{ question_content_forms[loop.index - 1].text_content|safe }}
            {% endif %}                             
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% if current_user.account_type == "Student" %}
    {{ submit_button.submit(class="btn btn-outline-success mt-3", value="Submit Assignment")}}
{% endif %}
</form>
```

When the user presses submit, I want to get every answer and put it into their own entry for the StudentQuestionSubmission table in my database. This is what that code looks like:

```
if request.method == "POST" and submit_button.data:
    print(request.form)
    index = 0
    for question in questions:
        question_to_submit = StudentQuestionSubmission(question_id = int(question.id),
                                                       student_id = int(current_user.id))
        if question.type == "code":
            question_to_submit.question_content = question_content_forms[index].code_content.data
        elif question.type == "text":
            question_to_submit.question_content = question_content_forms[index].text_content.data

        print(f"\n\n{ question_content_forms[index].code_content.data } \n \
        { question_content_forms[index].text_content.data } \n\n")
        index += 1
        db.session.add(question_to_submit)

    assignment_to_submit = StudentAssignmentSubmission(assignment_id = int(assignment_id),
                                                        student_id = int(current_user.id),
                                                        has_submitted = True,                                                    
                                                        submission_date = date.today())
    db.session.add(assignment_to_submit)
    db.session.commit()

    flash(f"'{assignment.name}' has been succesfully submitted.")
    return redirect(url_for('classroom_assignments_list', class_id = class_id, paper_id = paper_id))
```

You can see that I print the data of the textboxes. It will output 'asdf' on both iterations even if I wrote something entirely different for question 2.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

EDIT: 'hackily' getting the content from multiple instances of the same form using `request.form.to_dict(flat=False)['your_form_field']`

Here's the new code:

```
if request.method == "POST" and submit_button.data:
    code_content = request.form.to_dict(flat=False)['code_content']
    text_content = request.form.to_dict(flat=False)['text_content']
    code_content_index = 0
    text_content_index = 0
    for question in questions:
        question_to_submit = StudentQuestionSubmission(question_id = int(question.id),
                                                       student_id = int(current_user.id))
        if question.type == "code":
            question_to_submit.question_content = code_content[code_content_index]
            code_content_index += 1
        elif question.type == "text":
            question_to_submit.question_content = text_content[text_content_index]
            text_content_index += 1

        print(f"\n\n{ question_to_submit.question_content } \n\n")
        db.session.add(question_to_submit)

    assignment_to_submit = StudentAssignmentSubmission(assignment_id = int(assignment_id),
                                                        student_id = int(current_user.id),
                                                        has_submitted = True,                                                    
                                                        submission_date = date.today())
    db.session.add(assignment_to_submit)
    db.session.commit()

    flash(f"'{assignment.name}' has been succesfully submitted.")
    return redirect(url_for('classroom_assignments_list', class_id = class_id, paper_id = paper_id))
```

Comment: You have `[GetQuestionContent() for item in range(0, len(questions))]`.  What is the implementation of `GetQuestionContent`, it looks like it returned the same result.  Since it looks like all the questions are rendered inside the same `<form>` tag, you may want to instead try [`request.form.getlist()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566757/how-to-get-multiple-selected-items-from-form-in-flask) instead?

Comment: My code feels horrid right now, but you just helped me get everything working. Couldn't get `getlist()` working, but from the post you linked me, I saw `request.form.to_dict`. I am now storing the answers in a variable with `request.form.to_dict(flat=False)['code_content']` or `[text_content]` depending on the answer type. I'll update my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is not to create multiple forms, but to dynamically create one form for all the necessary questions.
In this case it is possible to assign a unique id to each field, which indicates that it belongs to the question.

The following example shows you a possible implementation.
An answer field is added to the form for each question, which has the id of the question in its name. Thus, the respective question can be assigned when rendering and querying the input data.

###### Flask

```py
from flask import (
    Flask,
    render_template,
    request
)
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import TextAreaField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
import random

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your secret here'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Question(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String)
    owner = db.Column(db.Integer)
    title = db.Column(db.String)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)

with app.app_context():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

    qs = [Question(
        type=random.choice(['code', 'text']),
        owner=1,
        title=f'Question {i+1}',
        description=f'Your description here.'
    ) for i in range(3)]
    db.session.add_all(qs)
    db.session.commit()

def form_factory(qs):
    class F(FlaskForm):
        submit = SubmitField('Submit')
    for q in qs:
        field = TextAreaField(
            q.type.title(),
            validators=[
                 # DataRequired()
            ],
        )
        setattr(F, f'q-{q.id}', field)
    return F

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    questions = Question.query.filter_by(owner=1).all()
    form = form_factory(questions)(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        for q in questions:
            field = getattr(form, f'q-{q.id}')
            print(f'Question-{q.id}\n{field.data}\n')
    
    return render_template('index.html', **locals())
```

###### HTML (templates/index.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container my-3">
      <form method="post">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

        <div class="accordion mb-3" id="accordionExample">
        {% for q in questions -%}
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading-{{loop.index}}">
            <button
              class="accordion-button collapsed"
              type="button"
              data-bs-toggle="collapse"
              data-bs-target="#collapse-{{loop.index}}"
              aria-expanded="false"
              aria-controls="collapse-{{loop.index}}"
            >
              {{ q.title }}
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div
            id="collapse-{{loop.index}}"
            class="accordion-collapse collapse"
            aria-labelledby="heading-{{loop.index}}"
            data-bs-parent="#accordionExample"
          >
            <div class="accordion-body">
              <div class="mb-3">
                {{ q.description|safe }}
              </div>
              {% set field = form|attr('q-{}'.format(q.id)) -%}
              <div>
                {{ field.label(class_='form-label') }}
                {{ field(class_='form-control' + ('', ' editor')[q.type=='code']) }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor -%}
        </div>

        <div class="d-grid gap-2">
          {{ form.submit(class_='btn btn-primary') }}
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What a genius solution! Thank you so much for this, it works exactly how I want. I even customised it a little bit for a different part of my web app. Thank you!!!